# Invalid connection string when connecting to database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to release a test application developed in c# + SQLite

It works fine in debug mode, but once I try to release it and run the .exe file, this error pops up.

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid ConnectionString format, cannot parse: string value to split cannot be null
   in System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ParseConnectionString(SQLiteConnection connection, String connectionString, Boolean allowNameOnly)
   in System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ParseConnectionString(SQLiteConnection connection, String connectionString, Boolean parseViaFramework, Boolean allowNameOnly)
   in System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   in System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   in System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   in System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   in PatientsManagementSystem.Login.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Simone\Documenti\SITI\Visual CSharp\PatientsManagementSystem\Login.cs:riga 41
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

These are some snippets of my code.

*App.config*

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DataSource" value="Data Source=E:\\User\\Documents\\Stuff\\Visual CSharp\\DB\\DbName.db;Version=3;"/>
</appSettings>
```

*MainClass.css*

```
class MainClass
{
    public string dataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSource"]; 
    ...
}
```

*Login.cs*

```
...
MainClass main = new MainClass();

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string pwd = txtPassword.Text;
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
  {
    string encPwd = EncryptDecryptStrings.GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, pwd);

    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(main.dataSource))
    {
      string sql = $"SELECT FullName FROM Users WHERE Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND Password = '" + encPwd + "';";
      SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
      da.Fill(dt);
      conn.Close();
      da.Dispose();
      conn.Dispose();
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

What's wrong in your opinion?
Why it works in debug mode? ConnectionString is the same one... of course.

**EDIT - Extra information**
The error is present also if I try to run the exe file contained into /obj/Debug folder
It looks like the App.config is not read properly outside Visual Studio

Comment: Does the path E:\\User\\Documents\  exist in the computer you deploy your program ??

Comment: Of course. I'm deploying the app on the same machine I developed it. I believe that some information are not included inside the .exe file (it's my first C# app... be patient, please )

Comment: No need for asking to be patient :). Do you use any logging, like log4net. If so, then try to log the value of `main.dataSource`. Then from the corresponding text file, you will see what's the value, when you try to execute your program.

Comment: If you don't use logging, please check this  https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/. In a few minutes, you could have that I suggested above.

Comment: @Christos. Problems solved... I was running the wrong file :(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Christos I discovered two good things.

1. ConnectionString was fine, and Log4Net is a very useful tool.
2. I was trying to execute the wrong file!!! The good one was, of course, the .exe file inside /bin folder and not the one inside /obj.

Am I stupid... maybe! :(